# Using open62541 in winforms application (C#) to read and write data from OPC UA Server

Tags: c#, winforms, dllimport, .net-4.8, open62541

I wrote a application with winform. my client application must be connect to an OPC UA server then write/read variables of OPC UA protocol. I choose open62541 for this situation, because open62541 is free and easy to use (if anyone have better solution, please say). in first step I downloaded open62541 source code. I changed this line of CMakeLists.txt to get dll and .c/.h file:

```
option(UA_ENABLE_AMALGAMATION "Concatenate the library to a single file open62541.h/.c" ON)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Enable building of shared libraries (dll/so)" ON)
```

Then [compile](http://www.open62541.org/doc/0.2/building.html#building-with-cmake-on-windows) source with this command:

```
cd open62541
mkdir build
cd build
cmake.exe .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
```

And then open open62541.sln in "Visual Studio 16 2019" and compile with release 64bit config. now I have open62541.dll/.c/.h/.lib and copy dll file to "WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Libraries",  but when i try to add open62541.dll to my project (Project>References>add references>Browse), I get this message

[image]

Comment: I would delete all the files and start from scratch.  Last year took me a couple of weeks to compile c# code a linux and to get it correct.  Previously the developer was compiling on windows and copying exe to linux.  I used the linux compiler and had a lot of issues.  I had to make changes and compile in the folder where the source was located in linux while in windows you were able to compile from parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an C# native stack use the [OPC Foundation stack](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard). It is also free and is a reference implementation. You can find samples for the stack [here](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples)

The open62541 is greate but it is written in C not in C#.So I think you need to manage/wrappe the code. Maybe the [reopen62541 project](https://github.com/jurihock/reopen62541) can helpt you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have problem with learning "UA-.NETStandard". UA-.NETStandard doesn't have updated and complete documentation (or maybe I cant find useful documentation resource). I just find this link but this is not complete: http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/help/index.htm